# Parse.com IAP: How to switch between production and sandbox mode?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com PFPurchase IAP library, but it doesn't say how to switch between Sandbox and Production modes.

I am using a Sandbox test account and the popup dialog shows that the Environment is Sandbox. However, I don't know if it will behave properly as a published app in the App Store.

Anyone else know the answer?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, now I'm one of those devs that answers their own question. (shame)

It seems Apple changed this recently so that the app knows whether you are using Sandbox or Production based on how the app was deployed. It wasn't that way before.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2259/_index.html

"Store Kit connects to the sandbox environment when you launch your application from Xcode, from your test device (iOS), or from the Finder (OS X). It connects to a production environment for applications that were downloaded from the App Store."

Comment: There's nothing shameful with acquiring the knowledge to answer your own question.  I'd say it's one of the best things that can happen to you. This community is extremely helpful, but at times you learn and grow faster than what it takes others to give you the answer.